# Convergence time of a Markov chain

Tags: references, stochastic-processes, markov-process

We know that a regular Markov chains converges to a unique matrix. The convergence time maybe finite or infinite. My interest is in the case where the convergence time is finite. How can we accurately determine this time or in other words the number of transitions for convergence? I am interested to go through the relevant materials needed to determine different methods that maybe out there to calculate this. If anyone could suggest a good reference to start off with I would be delighted. Any assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: See [these lecture notes](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/313/ConvergenceRates.pdf), especially part 3.